# Javascript Alert & Redirect script behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript

I was making a small little alert script for a blog on tumblr today, but I noticed that my script redirected no matter what they chose as decision.

They have the choice to click Confirm to enter the site(I'll call this alert X), or Cancel to let some other alert pop up telling them they'll be redirected to their dashboard (I'll call it alert Y). The problem is that the redirect can ONLY happen after OK is being clicked in the alert Y. Though, After clicking Confirm in alert X, it also redirects. Can anyone find out where I went wrong? I'm a newbie/noob @ Javascript; Still learning, Making progress!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=window.confirm("WARNING! This blog contains depressing content and possibly vivid imagery! Do you really want to continue? Click OK to continue; Click Cancel to leave now. ")
if (x)
    window.alert('You can now close this box and browse the blog!')
else
    var c=window.alert("It >Might< be better if you leave the blog now."); 
    window.location = "http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard"
</script>
```

Comment: look like a stackoverflow question

Comment: Flagged as off-topic. Definitely belongs in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = window.confirm("WARNING! This blog contains depressing content and possibly vivid imagery! Do you really want to continue? Click OK to continue; Click Cancel to leave now. ")
  if (x)
    window.alert('You can now close this box and browse the blog!')
  else {
    var c = window.alert("It >Might< be better if you leave the blog now.");
    window.location = "http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget the {} if you dont put {} javascript condition allow only one statement, so `windows.location` isn't in the condition and will always be triggered

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=window.confirm("WARNING! This blog contains depressing content and possibly vivid imagery! Do you really want to continue? Click OK to continue; Click Cancel to leave now. ")
if (x)
    {window.alert('You can now close this box and browse the blog!');}
else{
    var c=window.alert("It >Might< be better if you leave the blog now."); 
    window.location = "http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard";
}
</script>
```